# Start and Pause While Looping through db records

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, record

I have a page with some info about bills. I get this info with a simple while loop and echo it onscreen. I want that if a user clicks on 'Next Bills' that the next two bills are shown from the db rows. So a specific part of the page needs to be refreshed 'between the underscores' and the while loop needs to be paused at the first two rows, if the user activates the button, the while loop should continue and show the next two rows or two earlier rows.

I don't know how I can do this, where to start and what to look for. Is there a way to do this?

Starting Budget: 1040 Euros 
Current Budget : 1000 Euros 
_
|Companyname    : 20 Euros on 12/12/12 <-- First row of db
|Companyname    : 20 Euros on 16/01/13 <-- Second row of db
_

<< Earlier Bills      Next Bills >>

```
<?php
$sqBill= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bill WHERE idUser = '$_SESSION[idSelected]'",  $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqBill))
{       
    $company = $row['company'];
    $bill = $row['bill'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo '<div><label><b>' . $company . '</b></label><input type="text" value="' . htmlspecialchars($bill) . ' op ' . htmlspecialchars($date) . '" disabled></div>';    

}
?>
```

Comment: search for `pagination`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking into pagination and I have found [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html) example. I've been trying to implement it in the style of my website and it seems to be working out. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $limit = $limit + 2;
    }
    else {
        $limit = 0;
    }
    ?>

    <a href="yourPage.php?limit=<?= $limit; ?>">Next bill</a>
    <?php

    $sqBill= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bill WHERE idUser = '$_SESSION[idSelected]' LIMIT $limit, 2;");
```

Very simple example. However it should only 2 records LIMITed with starting by the first 2 and increasing by +2

Also adding simple condition, you can manipulate the previous page. All the secureness (sending the limit through another way, making it only integer, etc..) and further structuring (setting all the conditions into a method, etc...) are up to you ofcourse:

```
<?php

    if($limit > 0) {
        $previous = $limit - 4;

        ?>
        <a href="yourPage.php?limit=<?= $previous; ?>">Previous bill</a>
```